# SQL Server 2000:Invalid operator for data type. Operator equals add, type equals ntext

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I've got some code that runs all lovely on SQL Server 2008, however I'm forced to try it on SQL Server 2000 server, where it falls down.

Basically I'm looking to combine two columns, with a comma in-between.

```
SELECT COALESCE(cardesc1, '') + ', ' + COALESCE(cardesc2, '') AS "Car Summary" FROM macros;
```

Comment: Works fine on sql server 2000 for me.

Comment: It's because cardesc2 is an ntext, SQL 2000 doesn't seem to want to know.  cardesc1 is a varchar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it!

SELECT COALESCE(cardesc1, '') + ', ' + COALESCE(convert(varchar(100),cardesc2), '') AS "Car Summary" FROM macros;